# Can we call methods of non-static classes without an object in Java?

Tags: java, static, wrapper

The wrapper class `Integer` has the static method `parseInt()` which is used like this:

```
Integer.parseInt();
```

I thought only methods of static classes could be called like this (i.e. `Class.doMethod()`). All non-static classes need objects to be instantiated to use their methods.

I checked the API, and apparently `Integer` is declared as `public final Integer` - not static.

Comment: What do mean by "static class"?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the class is static -- it's whether the _method_ is static that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any class can contain both `static` and non-static methods. When calling the `static` methods on any class - including your own - you *don't* need to instantiate an instance of the class, just call the method using the class name: `MyClass.methodName()`.

In fact, even the following will work:

```
Integer nullInt = null;
nullInt.parseInt("5");
```

This works because only the class *type* of the reference is important when calling `static` methods. But consider this poor style: always use e.g. `Integer.parseInt` instead.

Also note that you can't declare a top-level class as `static` anyway: only nested/inner classes can be declared as static.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are wrong.

Only static methods can be called like this, but they may belong to 'non static' classes.

Answer (score 2):

In java, static methods may be called from objects, but this only generates a warning and still compiles.
A non-static class can have static fields and methods that are shared by all instances (this is why "Shared" means static in VB.NET). Therefore accessing a static member from an object can confuse the reader, and must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

A way to phrase it:  An `Integer` is a concrete object; you can have many `Integer`s.  There is only one `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

That's to say, there are some things with `Integer`s that are concrete, and others that only need to exist once, anywhere.

Comment: I found "`Integer` is a concrete object` a little confusing... *an* `Integer` is a concrete object, `Integer` is a class.